# AsyncTask Issue related to Notifications and IntentService

Tags: android

I have a pretty weird problem. I'm setting a notification in my Service in order to launch an Activity. When the Activity launches, an `AsyncTask` is started. This is how I set up the notification:

```
CharSequence tickerText = getString(R.string.notificationTextUpdates);
CharSequence contentText = getString(R.string.app_name);

Notification notification = new Notification(icon,
                        tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(
                        getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),
                        tickerText, contentText, contentIntent);
notifManager.notify(0, notification);
```

If the application is running, everything works, but if it wasn't running before, the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` method doesn't get fired. Instead I get the following exception:

> 09-30 16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{4057ec78} sending message to a
>   Handler on a dead thread 09-30 16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):
>   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196) 09-30
>   16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457) 09-30
>   16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430) 09-30
>   16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367) 09-30 16:07:52.500:
>   WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:350) 09-30 16:07:52.500:
>   WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:214) 09-30 16:07:52.500:
>   WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSet(FutureTask.java:253)
>   09-30 16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:113) 09-30
>   16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:311)
>   09-30 16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 09-30
>   16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   09-30 16:07:52.500: WARN/MessageQueue(27729):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

Strangely enough, this **doesn't** happen, when I set up the same notification inside another Activity, so everything works as intended.

I'm quiet confused. My Activity runs in SingleTask mode, I also tried SingleTop mode, which basicly didn't change anything.

Comment: i think you put thread and handler??????????

Comment: Could you please explain this a little more?

Comment: write your full code....................

Comment: There isn't much more code. The 'onCreate' method launches another method, which exececutes an AsyncTask. I can track the 'doInBackground' method, but the 'onPostExecute' isn't triggered, given the described circumstances.

Comment: Get rid of `singleTask` (replace with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` on your `Intent` in the `PendingIntent`, if desired). Get rid of `getApplicationContext()` (replace with `this`). Get rid of `getBaseContext()` (replace with `this`). See if those help.

Comment: I just implemented your tips, sadly it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915, which is a possible root cause of the problem. It includes a workaround for the issue.